# OrientDB distributed mode error: cannot find best cluster for class

Tags: distributed, orientdb

I've istalled orientdb in distributed mode but I'm experiencing some problems..

I've tried version 2.0.2, 2.0.4 and 2.1-SHAPSHOT.

Using a java client with Tinkerpop library, trying to insert a record, the DB throws an exception:

```
com.orientechnologies.common.exception.OException: Cannot find best cluster for class 'MYCLASS' on server 'node1'.
```

Another error that I noticed is:

```
Cannot route READ_RECORD operation for #-1:-3 to the distributed node
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot read record #-1:-3 since the position is invalid in database 'mydb'
```

Thank you very much

**Edit:**

I noticed that sometimes it works and I think I found in which case:

Start the first node with dserver.sh and then run the second one with dserver.sh too.

From my java Tinkerpop client, if I set the connection to the first node it doesn't work throwing "Cannot find best cluster", but if I configure it to connect to the second node.. it works!

If I start the second node before the first one, my client must be configured to point to the first node in order to make it work!

Hope it helps

**Edit 2**

Using 2.0.5 it seems to work, but now I have another problem during vertex deletion.

```
orientdb {db=dmd3}> delete edge #12:4

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Error on executing distributed request (id=124 from=node_2__test task=command_sql(delete edge #12:4) userName=) against database 'dmd3.[]' to nodes [node_2__test, node_1__test]

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Quorum 2 not reached for request (id=124 from=node_2__test task=command_sql(delete edge #12:4) userName=). Timeout=19ms Servers in timeout/conflict are:
 - node_1__test: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.delete edge #12:4
Received: {node_2__test=com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.delete edge #12:4, node_1__test=com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.delete edge #12:4}
```

This is the orientdb log

```
2015-03-16 14:35:01:981 WARNING [node_2__test] detected 1 node(s) in timeout or in conflict and quorum (2) has not been reached, rolling back changes for request (id=126 from=node_2__test task=command_sql(delete edge #12:4) userName=) [ODistributedResponseManager]
2015-03-16 14:35:01:985 WARNING [node_2__test] Quorum 2 not reached for request (id=126 from=node_2__test task=command_sql(delete edge #12:4) userName=). Timeout=12ms Servers in timeout/conflict are:
 - node_2__test: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.delete edge #12:4
Received: {node_2__test=com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.delete edge #12:4, node_1__test=com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.delete edge #12:4} [ODistributedResponseManager]
2015-03-16 14:35:01:985 WARNING [node_2__test] sending undo message for request (id=126 from=node_2__test task=command_sql(delete edge #12:4) userName=) to server node_2__test [ODistributedResponseManager]
2015-03-16 14:35:01:986 WARNING [node_2__test] sending undo message for request (id=126 from=node_2__test task=command_sql(delete edge #12:4) userName=) to server node_1__test [ODistributedResponseManager]Sent run-time exception to the client /127.0.0.1:39695: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Error on executing distributed request (id=126 from=node_2__test task=command_sql(delete edge #12:4) userName=) against database 'dmd3.[]' to nodes [node_2__test, node_1__test]
com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Error on executing distributed request (id=126 from=node_2__test task=command_sql(delete edge #12:4) userName=) against database 'dmd3.[]' to nodes [node_2__test, node_1__test]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.send2Nodes(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:194)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.sendRequest(OHazelcastPlugin.java:350)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedStorage.command(ODistributedStorage.java:258)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:63)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.command(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1178)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:385)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:220)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:69)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Quorum 2 not reached for request (id=126 from=node_2__test task=command_sql(delete edge #12:4) userName=). Timeout=12ms Servers in timeout/conflict are:
 - node_2__test: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.delete edge #12:4
Received: {node_2__test=com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.delete edge #12:4, node_1__test=com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Error on execution of command: sql.delete edge #12:4}
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedResponseManager.manageConflicts(ODistributedResponseManager.java:576)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedResponseManager.getFinalResponse(ODistributedResponseManager.java:340)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.waitForResponse(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:364)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.send2Nodes(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:191)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: It's an [issue](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2981).

Comment: Please can you try 2.0.5-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Using 2.0.5 it seems to work. I have anoher problem (see edit in the answer).
Thanks